# jQuery click function can't find the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

```
a = new object();
a.loadInterface();

$("button").click(function() {
    a.doSomething();
});
```

The problem is that `a.loadInterface()` is what loads the button into the DOM, and it happens at the end of a `$.post()` because data from the server is needed to populate some attributes of the button.

So what I think is going on is, JavaScript reads the `button.click` detector but at that time there is no button for it to bind to.

Any ideas?

Comment: For one, it's `new Object` with a capital letter.

Comment: I'm assuming that `object` is defined by some other library or framework, since `a.loadInterface()` is available on it.

Comment: @jmar777: You're correct, didn't notice that. (Bad variable naming of that library though...)

Comment: its not my real object name.  Was just using it as a placeholder.

Comment: @pimvdb: i agree with that. Hopefully there's no `array` or `string` as well :p

Comment: @Ryan, then consider `var a = new MyObject();` in the future, that removes all ambiguity about your custom type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assessment of the problem is correct.  A simple solution would be to use `delegate`.  E.g.,

```
$(document).delegate('button', 'click', function() {
    a.doSomething();
});
```

---

Edit: more info on `delegate` and why it works on dynamically created elements *after* event binding can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Please forgive my curiosity, but I'm seeing this pattern a lot lately, so I would like to know: why bother calling `delegate()` on `$(document)` instead of using `live()`, which does the same thing and is arguably simpler? Is there some reason I'm missing?

Comment: It's *very* similar to `live`, but different in that `delegate` won't actually run the 'button' selector simply to set up the event delegation. In the case of `live`, the API dictates that a query is run for `$('some-selector')`, even though that selector string is only needed for event delegation filtering. It was actually as a direct result of me wining about this that `delegate` landed in core. Some background can be found here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5877 and here: http://paulirish.com/2010/on-jquery-live/ (note that jQuery.live had been my proposal at the time).

Comment: `.delegate()` performs faster than `.live()`. http://jsperf.com/delegate-vs-live, http://jsperf.com/delegate-vs-live-2

Comment: There's two opportunities for performance improvements with `delegate`. First is the setup stage, since you don't needlessly run the query just to define your filter. Second is that you can delegate from lower in the DOM.  E.g., `$('table').delegate('tr', 'click', ...)` will perform better than `$('tr').live('click', ...)` even after the setup phase, because there are fewer events to filter, fewer DOM nodes to bubble up through before filtering, and a greater probability that the click event actually originated on a matching element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right. If you are creating button in based on the data returned from the post, you'll need to bind event in the method that is executed after the success of the post.